# get the errorbar showing the standard deviation using countplot from seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a data consisting of 3 columns having 2 category data as given below in [image: Table]:-

I want to get the errorbar showing the standard deviation using countplot from seaborn.
I have generated the barplot [image] using the code :-

```
ax = sns.countplot(x="variable",hue="value", data=pd.melt(data))
```

How can i get the errorbar using the countplot showing standard deviation.

Comment: You are _counting_ the number of elements within a column of type `Ours` or `Google`. The count is an exact number, it doesn't have a distribution, so it hasn't have a error

Answer (score 0):

Of such categorical data you can not calculate a mean and standard deviation. You could calculate a mean and standard deviation over all three Q (picture at the end):

First, let's create a df:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Q1':['Ours', 'Ours', 'Ours', 'Google', "Google", "Google", "Google", "Google" , "Google", "Google", "Google"],
        'Q2':['Ours', 'Ours', 'Ours', 'Ours', "Google", "Google", "Google", "Google", "Google", "Google", "Google"],
        'Q3':['Ours', 'Ours', 'Ours', 'Ours', "Ours", "Google", "Google", "Google",  "Google", "Google", "Google"]}
                    )
```

Then we can count how many times a category is present in each column and build a new df:

```
# get the count for each column:
Q1 = df['Q1'].value_counts()
Q2 = df['Q2'].value_counts()
Q3 = df['Q3'].value_counts()

# convert one pd.Series in a data frame. Add the others as new column
new_df = Q1.to_frame()
new_df['Q2'] = Q2
new_df['Q3'] = Q3

# convert the df to long format
new_df =  new_df.transpose()
new_df = new_df.melt()
```

The created dataframe:

```
  variable  value
0   Google      8
1   Google      7
2   Google      6
3     Ours      3
4     Ours      4
5     Ours      5
```

With this data we can make a barplot including a standard deviation:

```
ax = sns.barplot(x="variable", y="value", data=new_df, ci="sd")
ax.set(xlabel='over all three Q', ylabel='counts')

plt.show()
```

[image: barplot]